# Constructor with another template class as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++

I have this problem with template class. I want to make a constructor with another class as a parameter with a different type, but every time I try to initialize the attribute of the class I get error that it's private and I can't access it.
I would appreciate any help.

Here is the simple code:

```
template <typename Type>
class SomeClass {
    Type p;
public:
    SomeClass(Type x) { p = x; }
    template <typename Type2>
        SomeClass(SomeClass<Type2> k) { p = k.p; }
    Type GetP() { return p; }
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass<double> c(2.4);
    SomeClass<int> c1(c);
    std::cout << c1.GetP() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please realize that `SomeType<T>` and a `SomeType<U>` are two completely different types.  Therefore you can't access the private member variable since the types are unrelated.  So your issue isn't a template issue

Comment: I always knew that those are different types, but I thought that something with the templates was cause of  the problem. I'll keep that in mind next time, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare the class as friend:

```
template <typename Type>
class SomeClass {
    Type p;
public:
   template <typename Type2> friend class SomeClass;
    SomeClass(Type x) { p = x; }
    template <typename Type2>
        SomeClass(SomeClass<Type2> k) { p = k.p; }
    Type GetP() { return p; }
};
```

[*LIVE DEMO*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1864f4b651c7104d)

Answer (score 0):

`SomeType<T>` and `SomeType<U>` are different type and so cannot access private (nor protected) member the other class.

In your case, you may use your getter:

```
template <typename Type2>
SomeClass(const SomeClass<Type2>& k) { p = k.GetP(); }
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/qhcSig)

Comment: The getter will solve this problem, but it seems that declaring the class as a friend will solve my problems with more complex types. I appreciate your effort.